# Screenshots are not updated on G Suite Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I changed my app listing screenshots on the [Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) but the listing has not changed, even worse, it kept the links to the old screenshots and none of them was found (404 status codes).

This is the listing and you can see the 'not found' pictures: [Listing on G Suite Marketplace](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/shared_contacts_manager_for_g_suite/176603020899?pann=cwsdp).

Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to follow the [image size guidelines for screenshots](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing#screenshots):

> **Screenshots**
>
> You must provide at least one screenshot of your application and you can provide >up to a maximum of five screenshots.
> If your app supports multiple locales, you can provide locale-specific
> screenshots. Your screenshot should have square corners and no padding
> (full bleed).
>
> Screenshots should be **1280x800 pixels** in size. If necessary,
> screenshots **640x400 pixels** in size can be used.

Comment: The sizes are correct. Meanwhile I opened a ticket with the support. They sent me a couple of mails. After a day the pictures were propagated to G Suite Marketplace listing. I don't know if it was solved in response to my ticket or if it just need time but it is still an issue because the pictures were invisible for a whole day. I'm not changing them anytime soon though.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that some images are taken from the Chrome Web Store listing while others are taken from the Cloud Console's Google Apps Marketplace SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned a comment. Meanwhile I opened a ticket with the support. They sent me a couple of mails. After a day the pictures were propagated to G Suite Marketplace listing. I don't know if it was solved in response to my ticket or if it just need time but it is still an issue because the pictures were invisible for a whole day. I'm not changing them anytime soon though.